# Could not find com.google.ads.AdActivity

Tags: android, admob

[image: Project Explorer Window]

^ there is the image so you know I'm using sdk 3.2. There is more to this code, but basically this is everything for my java code inside my main one, and it doesn't load my ads when I go to load them.  There are no errors and nothing in my Main.XML for the ad  Basically the ad is not showing at all

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class LearningLettersActivity extends Activity

    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the adView    
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX); //<---My   Publisher Id there"    
        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given    
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"    \
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);   
        // Add the adView to it   
        layout.addView(adView);  
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad   
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more"
          android:versionCode="3"
          android:versionName="1.00">
    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
                android:name=".LearningLettersActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
</manifest>
```

Basically nothing is pooping up for my ads at all when I go to test it on my phone, I tried using the code below and still nothing.

```
AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest();
adrequest.setTesting (true);
adView.loadAd(adrequest);
```

I've also tried:

```
AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest();
adrequest.setTesting (true);
adrequest.setTestingDevices("HT0CWHL11423") //<--- the name of my phone that appears when I go to load the emulator tab
adView.loadAd(adrequest);
```

Result:

```
01-18 03:50:19.874: E/Ads(16938): Could not find com.google.ads.AdActivity, please make sure it is registered in AndroidManifest.xml.
01-18 03:50:19.874: E/Ads(16938): You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.
```

Comment: which target version you are using ...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the logcat for anything with the Tag `Ads`.  Specifically, look for something like:

> Ad Request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of inventory.

It is possible that you are not getting ads back because AdMob cannot fill an ad.

There are a couple of things to note here. `AdRequest.setTesting(true)`, which only used to set test mode for emulators, is deprecated in favor of `AdRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR)` for setting test mode on an emulator.  For setting a test device, the device id you are supposed to enter is a hashed device id, which you can find in the logcat as well if you are debugging on your device.

Finally, the picture that you're using shows you have the SDK included for a ButtonMasher app, but the code you provided looks like it's for a Letter Learning app.  Make sure you are indeed using 4.3.1 in this app.

Comment: oh I apologize I did put the wrong code up their, but they are both using the same code and actually in the letter learning app I use the same exact code for the ads, and all im getting at the top is a red box saying make sure you have adActivity decarled in your manifest? which it is

Comment: Well, the error does in fact mean that you need to have `android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                                   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>` in your manifest.  I would double/triple check that you actually have that manifest definition in the Letter Learning app.

Answer (score 0):

The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires Android 1.5 or later. **Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).**

So take android v3.2 as your target version for the latest copy (as your manifest file suggest that you have taken the latest one).

For more details please have a look on [this](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I changed my API to 3.2 and still nothing I have even made my sdk targetVersion 3.2 and its still not adding the ads into the correct spot, I just dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: yeah but I dont really know what im looking for in the logcat